# Paragraph indentation after using `\ensuremath`

Tags: macros, indentation, paragraphs, parindent

I have created a macro that writes the progressive number of the exercises in an exam sheet. The macros works in normal mode and in math mode, so that I am able to write something like this:

```
\esercizio How much is $1+1$?
Solve the following equation:
\[
   \esercizio x-1=0
\]
```

The problem is: there is always an indentation at the beginning of each paragraph, even if I set `\parindent=0pt`.

This is the code I'm using:

```
\newcounter{NumEsercizio}
\newcommand{\esercizio}[1][]{
  \stepcounter{NumEsercizio}
  \ensuremath{\mathbf{\theNumEsercizio}.
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}
    {}
    {\text{ [#1]}}}
}
```

How can I remove paragraph indentation before the exercise number?

[Edit]

This is a working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{parskip}

\parindent=0pt

\newcounter{NumEsercizio}
\newcommand{\esercizio}[1][]{%
  \stepcounter{NumEsercizio}%
  \ensuremath{\mathbf{\theNumEsercizio}.
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}
    {}
    {\text{ [#1]}}}
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
Risolvi le seguenti disequazioni:
\[
    \esercizio\quad\frac{(x^2-1)(x-2)^2}{x^2+2}\le0,\qquad
    \esercizio\quad x^2(16-x^2)\le0.
\]

\noindent
\esercizio Risolvi il seguente sistema col metodo di riduzione, 
poi rappresenta graficamente la soluzione:
\[
\begin{cases}
5x+2y=1\\
5x-y=-8
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I gave a suggestion for what I suppose you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Second Edit (with your working example):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcounter{NumExersize}
\newcounter{SubExersize}
% #1 is the depth inside the exersize
% #2 is the content of the exercise item
\newcommand{\esercizio}[2][1]{%
\ifnum#1=1 %
\setcounter{SubExersize}{0}%
\stepcounter{NumExersize}%
\arabic{NumExersize}. {\bfseries #2}
\else
\stepcounter{SubExersize}%
\ifnum\value{SubExersize}>1 %
\quad\quad\textbf{\alph{SubExersize}.\;}\else\textbf{\alph{SubExersize}.\;}\fi\ensuremath{\mathbf{#2}}%
\fi
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\esercizio{Risolvi le seguenti disequazioni:}
\[
    \esercizio[2]{\frac{(x^2-1)(x-2)^2}{x^2+2}\le0}\quad
    \esercizio[2]{x^2(16-x^2)\le0.}
\]

\noindent
\esercizio{Risolvi il seguente sistema col metodo di riduzione, 
poi rappresenta graficamente la soluzione:}
\[
\begin{cases}
5x+2y=1\\
5x-y=-8
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**Edit:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{NumEsercizio}
\newcommand{\esercizio}[1][]{%
\def\arg{#1}%
\stepcounter{NumEsercizio}%
\ensuremath{\mathbf{\theNumEsercizio}}.{\ifx\arg\empty \else{ \bfseries #1}\fi}%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\noindent\esercizio[How much is $1+1$?]

Solve the following equations:
\[
   \esercizio x-1=0
\]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**Old answer: (without realy understanding the command)**
Whith the help of `\noindent` and some"%" added:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcounter{NumEsercizio}
\newcommand{\esercizio}[1][]{%
\stepcounter{NumEsercizio}%
\ensuremath{\mathbf{\theNumEsercizio}.
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}
{}
{\text{ [#1]}}}
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\noindent\esercizio{How much is $1+1$?}
Solve the following equation:
\[
   \esercizio{x-1=0}
\]
\end{document}
```

The "%" symbol doesn't allow an empty space to be created during the execution of the command (search about "latex tokens")

The `\noindent` command just added out of the command because it doesn't make sense if the command is inside `\[\]` as in your second example.

Also, you have to enclose the command's arguments inside `{}` to meke clear what is the argument that the command takes as input.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works fine. I don't understand why should I enclose the text of the exercise inside `{}`: the macro works even without it.

Comment: It is just a best practice when you have an argument in a command, to make clear what is supposed to be the argument of it... May be in your case doesn't needed... but I don't even know if you would like to give to your command a whole paragraph or a whole line or what. This way every possible editor  of the document will have a more clear view of your code.. But may be in your case doesn't needed.

Comment: By mistake I used a wrong photo that shows the command with one space (I was ready to show you why you have the problem with the tokens but finally didn't)

Comment: I thought that the `\esercizio` macro doesn't have any argument, but actually I don't understand the second part of the macro, the one that starts with `\ifthenelse`. (Maybe I copied it from another macro, without understanding it completely)

Comment: @zar you have defined the command to have an optional argument try  `\esercizio[zzz]`  but the part with `\ifthenelse` isn't doing anything useful, also I can't see any reason to use `\ensuremath` here. as shown in the image, the layout with 1 in the text  and 2 in a centred equation just looks weird.

Comment: @zar... I just answered without completely understanding your code.. May be another example would be better for me to see the expected output... Just ignore it for now and I will try to find out if it is really needed

Comment: The idea is that some exercises start with a blodface number and a text, others have a brief introduction (such as: "solve the following equations") and then only formulas.

Comment: As @DavidCarlisle noticed, your command has just an optional argument, and so, my code has these extra `{}` that doesn't really do something instead of grouping the included text...(your command expects of just a possible optional argyment that would be enclosed inside `[]` and not `{}`) I don't really see the reason for this optional argument, and I suppose you could add (edit) in your post an example with the output you expect in some cases (At least one with an optional argument and one without)

Comment: @zar but why put the bold number there in the centred equation so it look like part of the mathematics, it will be massively confusing, why not put all the numbers in the same horizontal position. Look at the image above, anyone would read that as 2x-1 not as x-1 labeled equation 2

Comment: Ok, now I understand what was in my mind when I wrote this macro: the optional parameter writes an optional text after the exercise number, enclosed in `[]` (some special instruction for the students, for example). Never used, actually :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, because sometimes there are two short exercises in the same row. The example is confusing, when I use the macro inside display math mode, I always insert a `\quad` between the exercise number and the text.

Comment: @zar it's your document, but I don't think this helps your readers at all. (but +1 for this answer for doing what you ask anyway:-)

Comment: I'm open to suggestions. How do you propose to modify it? I will add a working example to my question.

Comment: zar: I just edited to what I supposed you meant... But as @DavidCarlisle mentioned , you will find a better answer and ideas after editing